# Is there a way to do this in one LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

I was thinking that it could be possible with `.Where()`.

```
public void RemoveExpiredEntries(List<CartEntry> entries)
{
    foreach (var entry in entries.Where(x => x.IsExpired()))
    {
        entry.Item.QuantityInCarts -= entry.Quantity;
    }
    entries.RemoveAll(x => x.IsExpired());
}
```

Comment: Are you planning on changing the code any more? It's now pretty significantly different to the original code... if I'd posted the answer I'd started writing, a lot of it would have been invalidated.

Comment: What is the point of changing the quantity of items and then removing them? Are they referenced somewhere else?

Comment: @JonSkeet The original code didn't compile. I had been messing around with it and ended up posting the wrong version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a (readable) solution where you can do it with a single statement. What you are doing is not a "query", it is an operation (or two) for some items which are already found using `Where`.

I would probably do the following:

```
var expiredEntries =  entries.Where(x => x.IsExpired()).ToArray();
foreach (var entry in expiredEntries)
{
    entry.Item.QuantityInCarts -= entry.Quantity;
}
entries.RemoveAll(expiredEntries );
```

Or

```
foreach (var entry in entries.Where(x => x.IsExpired()).ToArray())
{
    entry.Item.QuantityInCarts -= entry.Quantity;
    // remove works here, because it created an array with expired items.
    entries.Remove(entry);
}
```

Which are both actually not very different to what you are doing. Replacing the `foreach` with `.ForEach` looks more like linq, but doesn't change it much.

---

You may also consider **encapsulating** the atomar operation "RemoveEntry" within a class that holds and manages the list:

```
class Cart
{
    List<CartEntry> entries;

    public void RemoveEntry(CartEntry entry)
    {
        entry.Item.QuantityInCarts -= entry.Quantity;
        entries.Remove(entry);
    }

    public void RemoveExpiredEntries()
    {
      foreach (var entry in entries.Where(x => x.IsExpired()).ToArray())
      {
          RemoveEntry(entry);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot modify a collection while enumerating it. Therefore no LINQ expression can be applied.

LIN*Q* is designed to support queries, which by definition don't modify their source.

Answer (score 0):

Only way I can see you doing it with one line, but it isn't the nicest to read.

```
public void RemoveExpiredEnties(List<CartEntries> entries)
    {
        (entries.Where(e => e.IsExpired).ToList()).ForEach(item => entries.Remove(item));
    }
```